# Insert new line in xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I want to insert a line of code in between any MeasureSymbolGroup line in the xml file.I have some code but its not working properly.

My code:

```
tree = ET.parse(PATH_XML_FILE)
root = tree.getroot()
for sub in sorted(my_array):
    setSubValue = False
    for neighbor in root.iter('Command'):
        if "SWF" in str(neighbor.attrib):                
            if re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(sub) + r"\b", neighbor.text): # match whole word only
                setSubValue = True
                break

    if setSubValue == False:
        print sub
        f = ET.Element('Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true"' + sub +'\n')

        neighbor.insert(1, f)
tree.write(output.xml')
```

Where my_array is an array with list of string.

Base xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<T1Automation>
    <Title>AutomationTest</Title>
    <LogFilePath>..\Result\log.html</LogFilePath>
    <Script Name="Group Measurement" GuiVisible="true" ShowTraces="true" StoreTraces="true" ShutdownConnection="false">
        <Commands>
            <Command Cmd="PrintTime" />            

            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">aaa</Command>             
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">bbb</Command> 
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">ccc</Command>
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">ddd</Command>          
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">eee</Command>         
            <Command Cmd="DownloadMeasurement" LogIt="true"/>       
            <Command Cmd="PrintTime" />

        </Commands>
    </Script>
</T1Automation>
```

Required xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<T1Automation>
    <Title>AutomationTest</Title>
    <LogFilePath>..\Result\log.html</LogFilePath>
    <Script Name="Group Measurement" GuiVisible="true" ShowTraces="true" StoreTraces="true" ShutdownConnection="false">
        <Commands>
            <Command Cmd="PrintTime" />            

            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">aaa</Command>             
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">bbb</Command> 
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">ccc</Command>
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">ddd</Command>     
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">xxx</Command>             
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">eee</Command>         
            <Command Cmd="DownloadMeasurement" LogIt="true"/>       
            <Command Cmd="PrintTime" />

        </Commands>
    </Script>
</T1Automation>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<T1Automation>
    <Title>AutomationTest</Title>
    <LogFilePath>..\Result\log.html</LogFilePath>
    <Script Name="Group Measurement" GuiVisible="true" ShowTraces="true" StoreTraces="true" ShutdownConnection="false">
        <Commands>
            <Command Cmd="PrintTime" />            

            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">aaa</Command>             
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">bbb</Command> 
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">ccc</Command>
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">ddd</Command>          
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">eee</Command>         
            <Command Cmd="DownloadMeasurement" LogIt="true"/>

            <Command Cmd="Print" Format="Bold">Test finished</Command>
            <Command Cmd="PrintTime">
                <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true"fff/>
                <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true"ggg/>
           </Command>
        </Commands>
    </Script>
</T1Automation>
```

Comment: whtespace between tags are ignored by xml parsers so why bother

Comment: What specifically you are having the problem with ? Please post a minimal example.

Comment: Have you seen my new updated file with example? Please check once and give some idea.

Comment: You have not provided complete code or a clear description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hello @Bhansa,  I want to insert a new line in between  <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">aaa</Command>             
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">bbb</Command> but in my code it insert after this code.
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">ccc</Command>
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">ddd</Command>          
            <Command Cmd="MeasureSymbolGroup" FlexType="SWF" LogIt="true">eee</Command> but it insert after these lines